# Mountain bike routes in Val di Sole, Trentino?

Tags: italy, outdoor-activities

What are some popular, intermediate-level mountain-biking routes in Val di Sole (Trentino, Italy)?

Comment: Did you try www.wikiloc.com?

Comment: You might consider migrating this to Bicycles.SE.

Comment: Did you ask this question at [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)? I can migrate it for you.

Comment: It's really more of a travel question than a bicycle question...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to some routes.  Some of this is available in English, too.

http://www.valdisole.net/cms-01.00/articolo.asp?IDcms=1800&s=837&l=EN

Answer (score 3):

For biking, hiking, and all other mountain sports in the alpes I really can recommend www.hikr.org

It is a collection of tours, often with really great reviews, pictures and ratings.